# Process stats from big table

Tags: php, mysql, bigdata

I have an advertising site and I'm struggling to find the most efficient way to process statistics. My goal is to show unique visitors and clicks per day.

This is how it works: publishers can add a website and then add unlimited adspaces to it, so they can have multiple banners running on the same page or different pages.

```
WEBSITES
id | url

ADSPACES
id | website_id | info

VIEWS
id | adspace_id | ip | date (YYYY-MM-DD)

ADSPACES_STATS
id | adspace_id | views | date (YYYY-MM-DD)

WEBSITES_STATS
id | website_id | views | date (YYYY-MM-DD)
```

The script to update views and clicks for adspaces is already done:

```
$getViewsByAdspace = $db->query('SELECT count(*) as views, adspace FROM views WHERE date="'.date('Y-m-d').'" GROUP BY adspace ORDER BY id ASC');
while($getViewsForAdspace = $getViewsByAdspace->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $adspaceId = $getViewsForAdspace['adspace'];
    $adspaceViews = $getViewsForAdspace['views'];

    if( $db->query('UPDATE adspace_stats SET views='.$adspaceViews.' WHERE adspace='.$adspaceId.' AND date="'.date('Y-m-d').'"')->rowCount() == 0 )
        $db->exec('INSERT IGNORE INTO adspace_stats (adspace, date, views, clicks) VALUES ('.$adspaceId.', "'.date('Y-m-d').'", '.$adspaceViews.', 0)');
}
```

The script runs every hour.

Now I need a script to update statistics for websites. I can't find a efficient way to do that, the script above takes about 20 seconds with a table of 10M entries, which is perfect.

**The only way I see is this:**

Get all adspaces that belong to a website and then query like this: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip) as views FROM views WHERE (adspace=x OR adspace=Y ...) AND date=today`

Comment: You're using PDO, which is great, but be sure to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). What you've got here is probably full of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because of your reckless use of string concatenation.

Comment: @tadman it's probably a cron job, where would the sql injection come from ?

Comment: @Marius.C When you *assume* everything's okay, that's when you get into trouble. Just do it properly the first time and you won't have problems in the future.

Comment: that's correct. agree.

Comment: @tadman Wouldn't that slow down the execution time significantly?

Comment: @yesthisis **NO**. Stop *assuming* everything's okay and just do it correctly. This is sloppy code. Period. Stop making excuses. Prepared statements are not slower and not harder to use. They get your quoting right 100% of the time if used correctly and will save you hours of frustration in the future when someone puts a single `'` in your data somehow.

Comment: @tadman Sorry, I deleted my comment before I saw this last comment. I agree, it's better to play safe. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about sounding like such a jerk here, but some day you might be making a site people are putting personal information into and I do not want to read a headline about that database getting leaked. As developers we need to be disciplined about this, we have a responsibility.

Comment: have you tried an INSERT SELECT with joins to aviod that OR ?

Comment: @Marius.C THB I don't use JOINs in years, I don't really remember how I go about doing that. I've been trying that for the last hour or so, I'm sure I'll remember eventually.

Comment: I'm sure you'll do :) I think will work faster that way. Also maybe  splinting data across multiple tables like `VIEWS_OCTOMBER_YEAR` .. just an idea because I see that more experienced people don't bother to help with this one.

Answer (score 0):

It sucks but it works.

```
$websites = $db->query('SELECT * FROM websites WHERE state=0 ORDER BY id ASC');
while($website = $websites->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $query='';
    $getAdspacesByWebsite = $db->query('SELECT * FROM adspaces WHERE state=1 AND website='.$website['id'].' ORDER BY id ASC');
    while($adspace = $getAdspacesByWebsite->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $query.='OR adspace="'.$adspace['uniqid'].'" ';
    }
    if( $query!='' ) {
        $query = 'SELECT count(DISTINCT ip) as views FROM views WHERE date="' . date('Y-m-d') . '" AND (' . substr($query, 3) . ') ORDER BY id ASC';

        $result = $db->query($query)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if( $db->query('UPDATE websites_stats SET views='.$result['views'].' WHERE website='.$website['id'].' AND date="'.date('Y-m-d').'"')->rowCount() == 0 )
            $db->exec('INSERT IGNORE INTO websites_stats (website, date, views, clicks) VALUES ('.$website['id'].', "'.date('Y-m-d').'", '.$result['views'].', 0)');
    }
}
```